# jQuery: clicking nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup

```
<ol>
    <li class="ListItem">
        <span class="sub">@qItem.CategoryText</span>
        <input type="image" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/just-bins/256/bin-red-full-icon.png" width="30" class="deleteIcon" name="QuestionId" value="@qItem.Id" />
    </li>
</ol>
```

and the following script

```
$(".ListItem").click(function(){
doActionA();
});

$(".deleteIcon").click(function(){
doActionB();
});
```

---

When I click in image, it also triggers click of ListItem. I understand this is because image is inside ListItem. but I want ListItem's click not to be fired when image is clicked.
Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$(".deleteIcon").click(function(e){
    doActionB();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

```
$(".deleteIcon").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
    doActionA();    
});
```

The event you binded with delete icon is firing the parent event binding with ListItem, so you need to stop propagation for parent event when child is source of event.

Comment: he wants to prevent click event of parent when clicked on child. Dont you think the `event.stopPropagation()` should be added on child's click?

Comment: The event binding will child will not trigger event for parent.

Comment: I think it does, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/WtxLC/
Try commenting the `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: I could not see the code in jsFiddle there is something wrong ?

Comment: I have used `stopPropagation` on `.deleteIcon`. Can you explain why it worked? And if I remove it from there parent handler is also called.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteIcon", function() {
  doActionB();
});
```

This method is the only one I found to work with nested elements, especially those generated by a library such as Pivottable (https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".deleteIcon").click(function(){
    doActionA();
    return false;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .one(), as directed in the JQuery documentation.