# Click function on div inside div with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I wanted to know how you could stop the outer divs click function, and only have the inner divs click function be triggered. But, I want to stay using the $(document).on('click',selector) method for use in my application. I have see a few answers, but none that work with that method. Maybe An oversight by me?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Name').text('A veery long namemmmmmmeehhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhheeeee');
  $(document).on("click", ".task", function() {

    alert("click");
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".Name", function() {

    alert("click");
  });
});
```

```css
.one {
  height: 495px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 35%;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  outline: solid red 1px;
}

.two {
  height: 210px;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 15%;
  outline: solid red 1px;
}

.flex {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.Box {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 85%;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.Name {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 85%;
  max-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.Date {
  margin: 0px;
}

.task {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: solid #eaeaea 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #eaeaea 1px;
}

.Details {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 85%;
}

.three {
  height: 210px;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 35%;
  outline: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">

  <div class="one">
    one
    <div class="task task-container" data-type="yes">
      <div class="Details">
        <div class="Box">
          <p class="Name">A very long nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmee</p>
          <p class="Date">Due: 4/10/2018</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    three
    <div class="task task-container" data-type="yes">
      <div class="Details">
        <div class="Box">
          <p class="Name"></p>
          <p class="Date">Due: 4/10/2018</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

LINK- https://jsfiddle.net/t29ffzan/35/

Comment: check out `event.stopPropagation()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Why do you have them nested like this?  Just separate them and you won't have this problem.

Comment: Its a div with multiple functionalities. Both need to have click functions. THat doesn't apply. @jmargolisvt

Comment: In the future, please make sure you include at least the HTML along with the JavaScript **in the question itself** so that people can see what the problem is without having to go to jsfiddle.net (which is often blocked by corporations).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: clicking nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209371/jquery-clicking-nested-elements)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to capture the event within the function call:
`function(event) {}`
Next you call a function to `stopPropagation` within the function, like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".Name", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    alert("click");
});
```

[docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

In your second event handler, do the following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".Name", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("click");
});
```

It will prevent the event from bubbling, i.e. being also called on parent tags.
Look here for moar info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation.

Answer (score 0):

In the click handler for the inner element, stop the click from propagating outward (bubbling up).

```
  $(document).on("click", ".task", function() {
    alert("click");
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".Name", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("click");
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t29ffzan/36/